# Odd error with UIAlertView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

My code is breaking on something I don't believe I've changed (although that may be naive).

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if(buttonIndex==0) //breaks here
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"unwindFromCaseToMain" sender:self];
    }

}
```

This is the error, from a method which seemed to be working fine before and I'm almost certain I didn't change.

[image]

The code doesn't have any warnings or errors, and runs fine until I use the UIAlertView that calls this method.

Comment: So what is an error exactly ? because it looks like you just have a break point there.

Comment: Oh Christ, you're right. I am an utter, sleep-deprived, idiot. Anyhow, thanks for pointing that out the problem.

Comment: Yeah maybe just delete that question ;)

Comment: Tried to, but it has answers so I can't. A quick Google I did prior to this shows other people having the same "issue" as me, so maybe my torture over a breakpoint will help others :D

Comment: OK So i post answer ;)

Comment: Perhaps a shot of espresso from Starbucks will help with the situation. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not an error, I simply didn't understand how to use breakpoints and apparently I had placed a breakpoint in at this line of code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a breakpoint not really a crash.

You can confirm that by looking at description on right side saying "breakpoint" on green label.

Check Xcode breakpoint section by pressing CMD + 7 and turn them off.